# How to fix 'declared but not used' compiler error in this simple program?

Tags: go, declaration

I am trying to learn Go. I really don't understand why the compiler is saying that I am not using a variable. It seems to me that I am using the variable as an argument to `Println`.

My textbook states:

> In this for loop `i` represents the current position in the array and
>   `value` is the same as `x[i]`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    x := [5]float64{ 1,2,3,4,5 }
    i := 0
    var total float64 = 0

    for i, value := range x {
        total += value
        fmt.Println(i, value)
    }   
    fmt.Println("Average:", total / float64(len(x)))
}
```

Output on OS X:

```
go run main.go 
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:8: i declared and not used
```

Surely this `fmt.Println(i, value)` is using the variable `i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to fix the compiler message?

Remove the outer `i` from your program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    x := [5]float64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    var total float64 = 0

    for i, value := range x {
        total += value
        fmt.Println(i, value)
    }
    fmt.Println("Average:", total/float64(len(x)))
}
```

> Surely this fmt.Println(i, value) is using the variable i?

Yes, but the one you're defining inside the `for` loop. (note the `:=`), here:

```
for i, value := range x
    ^        ^
```

The outer variable `i` is never used.